# Spring Integration http endpoint from child context doesen't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

When I configure Http inbound channel adapter in the root context it works:

```
    <int-http:inbound-channel-adapter id="httpInbount" path="test" channel="ch.http.in" />

        <int:channel id="ch.http.in" />

        <int:service-activator input-channel="ch.http.in" output-channel="ch.aggr.obj" ref="httpToObjTransformer" method="transform"></int:service-activator>
        <bean id="httpToObjTransformer" class="com.nevexis.dcard.integration.transformer.HttpToObjTransformer" />

        <int:channel id="ch.aggr.obj">
            <int:queue />
        </int:channel>
```

But when I load it from a child context it's not registered.

```
 <int:channel id="ch.aggr.obj">
                <int:queue />
            </int:channel>
```

is in the root context and I load

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <int-http:inbound-channel-adapter id="httpInbount" path="transaction" channel="ch.http.in" />

    <int:channel id="ch.http.in" />

    <int:service-activator input-channel="ch.http.in" output-channel="ch.aggr.obj" ref="httpToObjTransformer" method="transform"></int:service-activator>
    <bean id="httpToObjTransformer" class="com.nevexis.dcard.integration.transformer.HttpToObjTransformer" />
</beans>
```

as a child `GenericXmlApplicationContext`.

When the child context is laoded I can see

```
IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping:197 - Mapped "{[/transaction],methods=[GET || POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public abstract void org.springframework.web.HttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws javax.servlet.ServletException,java.io.IOException
```

in the log, but `http://localhost:8081/transaction` can't be mapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `DispatcherServlet` is defined in the separete child context and it doesn't see `IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean.

Any child context can see beans from its `ancestors`, but not from other child context as well as the parent context can't see bean in your children.

There is need to understand why you want declare integration flow in the child context. Why isn't `<context:import>` enough for you?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was afraid that this is the case. The reason to declare the http endpoint in child context is that I want to add/remove endpoints while the application is running. I do the same with Websphere MQ and it works. If you can direct me to a better solution, it will be great.